# Facebook Graph API: collecting group statistics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am member of a facebook group, and the group is now growing to more than 2000 members, and somebody asked a question: where everybody was from. Cool question: nice to know.

That got me thinking: wouldn't there be a more convenient way to get this information? So I went looking for some API, found the Facebook Graph API, found the [API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and dove right in.

So I create a token, and inside that token I generally declare what I am allowed to acces, but this token can only access ... the things *I* can access.

So, for instance it is possible for me to

- list my groups
- list members of one of those groups

So I assumed I would be able to get public info for those members, hoping I could find age/gender/location, and then I could create a map/dashboard of some kind, which would be cool.

But afaik that is not possible. If I request the details of a user, I get only the most basic info:

```
{
  "id": "...", 
  "first_name": "...", 
  "last_name": "...", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/.../", 
  "name": "...", 
  "updated_time": "2014-09-12T17:02:18+0000"
}
```

I attempted to get more fields, using the `/#{user-id}?fields=gender,location` but that does not show anything more. In a way logical, because my token does not allow me to access this particular user, only my own user (right?).

So my question is in general: how can I gather statistics of a facebook group?

Possible solutions I can think of:

- request a token from all members, so I can collect their info? This seems completely impractical.
- for each member I can visit their *public* facebook page, and scrape the public info

But as a total Facebook API noob I am guessing there should be better ways? Also I am actually not interested in the personal data, just the generic statistics of a group, but from the API documentation I did not find any entry for that.

Or should I create an APP and all members of a group have to "install that APP" and then you can install that APP in the group which would add an extra page??? (ok: obviously also a Facebook APP noob).

All help, tips or remarks are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Facebook API as you noticed will only give you extended info pertaining to yourself. To get extended information for other users, those use must sign into an app that you own and grant access.

You are probably looking for `location` which requires `user_location` permission https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-user_location. Seeing that you will be using this for statistical purposes I don't believe you will permission request to Facebook will be reviewed.

With respect to your solutions

- request a token from all members, so I can collect their info? This seems completely impractical. *Agreed and you will not be approved for this permission anyway*
- for each member I can visit their public facebook page, and scrape the public info. *You are violating the TOS and Developer policy here*

So there is no way within the API, within policy to determine group statistics.

**What follows is not recommended and just shows it is practical but not a good way to go about it**

Facebook Native apps (Facebook for IOS/Android, Facebook Messenger, Facebook Pages) have special access to data and in addition are still running v1.0. Theoretically, one can use the access_token belonging to one of these apps then request the data `/{group-id}/members?fields=id,gender,location` is one way to do it.

Also all v1.0 applications still return the gender field for any user.

Comment: Bummer, v1 API is only available to apps created before April 2014, so this means there is now, for me, no way :( I guessed counting the number of members, and filters (search for all members that are male/female/...) but the API does not seem to allow such a thing either. In some way logical: I guess Facebook wants to be the only who can monetise on their users demographics to show correct ads and such. Thanks!